# OLS model fitting returns less number of coefficients as expected

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, statsmodels

I want to get the OLS coefficients for an equation like:

```
y=a+ax1+ax2+...+ax8
```

I have the code below, but I just get 7 coefficients instead of 8. I was expecting 8 coefficients. Why this is happening?

```
yy = [498.0, 238.0, 339.0, 172.0, 310.0, 249.0, 195.0, 173.0, 332.0, 204.0]
xx = [[8.333334, 930397626.0, 322654980.0, 2, 161.0, 29.0, 1999.999, 12335088.0],
      [8.333334, 978809835.0, 927942625.0, 3, 85.0, 1.0, 1999.999, 12335088.0],
      [100.0, 1168151674.0, 309743797.0, 4, 208.0, 29.0, 1999.999, 12335088.0],
      [100.0, 903582453.0, 346402518.0, 4, 156.0, 30.0, 1999.999, 12335088.0],
      [8.333334, 930397626.0, 322654980.0, 4, 156.0, 30.0, 1999.999, 12335088.0]]

X = np.array(xx)
Y = np.array(yy)
results = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
print results.summary()



             coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1             6.2988      2.479      2.541      0.085        -1.592    14.189
x2         -1.108e-05   4.63e-06     -2.392      0.097     -2.58e-05  3.66e-06
x3         -2.061e-05   5.85e-06     -3.521      0.039     -3.92e-05 -1.98e-06
x4           523.1934    208.974      2.504      0.087      -141.854  1188.241
x5            33.2000     17.488      1.898      0.154       -22.455    88.855
x6          -545.1934    168.326     -3.239      0.048     -1080.881    -9.506
x7          3.675e-07   1.11e-07      3.307      0.045      1.39e-08  7.21e-07
const          0.0023      0.001      3.308      0.045      8.61e-05     0.004
```

Comment: Your data doesn't look right, the response `Y` has 10 items and `X` is (4*8), it rise `ValueError: endog and exog matrices are different sizes`

Comment: Maybe I am doing this wrong. XX is a matrix represented as a double-list.
[ [x01,x02,x03,x04,x05,x06,x07,x08]
  [x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18] ]

yy = [498.0, 238.0, 339.0, 172.0, 310.0]

Comment: Maybe I am doing this wrong. XX is a matrix represented as a double-list.
[ [x01,x02,x03,x04,x05,x06,x07,x08]
  [x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18] ]

yy is more elements than it should by mistake. In this case, xx has 5 rows, so yy must have 5 elements.
yy = [498.0, 238.0, 339.0, 172.0, 310.0]

I don't understand why I don't get the x8. I will use the coefficients to predict y value based on my new x values. I am expecting have 8 'x1...x8' values that I will multiply with the coefficients. and then add the constant. Am I right?

Like this:
predicted y = coef1*value1 + ... + coef8*value8 + const

Comment: The summary table gives you the parameters. If you want predicted y, then look at `fittedvalues` or the predict method for new x.

Comment: I don't know how your list of list works, but `np.asarray(XX)` needs to have observations in the rows and variables in the columns. If you have it reversed, then you can either use `np.column_stack(XX)` or transpose `np.asarray(XX).T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 8 coefficients.

Assuming that your complete data look similar:

The last one is called `const` instead of `x8` because that column doesn't have any variation and is identified as constant.

You can specify names for the parameters, or you can add a very small noise in one of observation of the last column.

Comment: This is probably not the reason here, the second from the last is also a constant.

Comment: I assume the OP has a larger dataset that produced the results. If there are more than one constant columns, than I think the first one is identified as constant, at least that gets the label in an example that I tried.